# Optimize Postgis contour lines DB

Tags: postgis, mapnik, contour, optimization, geohash

I'd like to try to optimize a world-wide 10m contour lines (isohypses) Postgis database(from SRTM).

The complete DB takes 504GB on disk, contour lines are already in epsg:3857, and simplified with ogr2ogr at 4m. The DB is used for rendering tiles with Mapnik.
What I tried so far is:

- convert elevation to smallint instead of numeric(12,3).
- add a boolean column to 50m and 100m lines instead of using the % operator in mapnik queries, indexed or not.
- CLUSTER using ST_GEOHASH().

The results are shown below for a 20x20km and a 50x50km box obtained on a 7200rpm HDD, and I'm a bit disappointed cause I expected huge improvements.
These test results are obtained on a small 630MB extract (~550x750km in the Alps).

I'm not surprised the clustering did not add much improvement: the contours lines have been pushed into Postgresql sequentially from 1x1° shapefiles, so the disk order is probably fine enough.

[image]

***Question: Maybe I made mistakes in my method, or maybe I forgot to try something else ? Any suggestions ?***

More details below.

*Convert elevation from numeric() to smallint:*

```
ALTER TABLE contours ALTER COLUMN height TYPE smallint;
```

*Boolean column for 50m lines:*

```
ALTER TABLE contours ADD COLUMN _50m boolean;
UPDATE contours SET _50m = NOT CAST( height % 50 AS BOOLEAN );
CREATE INDEX _50m_geom_idx ON contours (_50m);
```

*Cluster by geohash:*

```
DROP INDEX contours_geom_idx;
CREATE INDEX contours_geohash ON contours (ST_GeoHash(ST_Transform(wkb_geometry,4326)));
CLUSTER contours USING contours_geohash;
DROP INDEX contours_geohash;
CREATE INDEX contours_geom_idx ON contours USING GIST (wkb_geometry);
```

*A typical query (adapted from mapnik queries):*

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT ST_AsBinary("wkb_geometry") AS geom 
FROM 
(SELECT wkb_geometry,height::integer FROM contours WHERE _50m) AS "contours-50" 
WHERE "wkb_geometry" && ST_SetSRID('BOX2D(698000 5678000,748000 5728000)'::box3d, 3857);
```

*Drop cache between each test query:*

> sudo sync;
>
> sudo service postgresql stop;
>
> sudo echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches;
>
> sudo service postgresql start